# composer install error

Tags: 8, composer

I can't install anything because of this error:

> [RuntimeException]
>     Could not scan for classes inside "/app/vendor/symfony/serializer/src/" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder

and subsequently:

> Could not scan for classes inside "/app/vendor/symfony/yaml/src/" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder

I navigated to that directory and the src folder is indeed missing...

I'm using Lando and switch the PHP to 7.1. I tried deleting the vendor directory and rerunning `lando composer update` and `lando composer install` but get the same errors.

Comment: Have you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @Clive this comment solved an issue I was facing. Would you care to add an answer that explains what's going on with that?

Comment: You can safely delete the vendor directory, if it exists, and then run `composer install` again.

Answer (score 0):

Could be and over lap of composer requests. This example is for Pantheon resipe but it may help https://github.com/lando/lando/issues/340